# Sharepoint library column button with condition

Tags: json, sharepoint

got customized "button" column in SharePoint library.

And I want the button to be visible only where value in another column called "Name" contain string "Permission".

My JSON:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "button",
"customRowAction": {
  "action": "executeFlow",
  "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"6b294902-f477-4657-819e-74bcfd2c92af\"}"
},
"attributes": {
  "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
},
"style": {
  "border": "2px solid black",
  "background-color": "transparent",
  "cursor": "pointer",
  "visibility": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              "[$Name]",
              "CONDITION"
            ]
          },
          "visible",
          "hidden"
        ]
      }
},
"children": [
  {
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "Update permissions"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use indexOf to check if the field conatins "Permission" string, please see the modified Json below:

```
 {
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "button",
"customRowAction": {
  "action": "executeFlow",
  "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"6b294902-f477-4657-819e-74bcfd2c92af\"}"
},
"attributes": {
  "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
},
"style": {
  "border": "2px solid black",
  "background-color": "transparent",
  "cursor": "pointer",
  "visibility": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$FileLeafRef]),'permission') != -1, 'visible','hidden')"
},
"children": [
  {
    "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "Update permissions"
  }
]
}
```

[image]

Reference:

[Formatting Values Using “Contains” in List Formatting](https://thechriskent.com/2019/02/06/formatting-values-using-contains-in-list-formatting/)

Comment: Hello Jerry, thank you unfortunatelly not working. Maybe problem is, that column "Name" is basically a Title column and I'm struggling to make a reference.  In edit view this column is called - "Name (linked to document with edit menu)".

Comment: @kyon84, so this should be a library and the Name field is the default Name field, use [$FileLeafRef] for the field name. I've updated the Json, please check.